# Excel Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, power-query

Want to create 3 queries that have a column filter in them. Rather than set the filter value by using a hard value I would like the filter value to be decided by a cell value in the workbook.
So rather than this in my query : 
= Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows2", each [Region] = "Hospitality and Leisure LC")

I want to have a cell reference instead of 'Hospitality and Leisure LC" . The cell in question will be a drop down cell where the user will select a name of a business type- This will save me creating a further 12 versions of the 3 initial queries (36 queries in total)

Comment: take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1303378/use-a-cell-value-for-a-paramater-value-using-in-power-query

Comment: if you find a solution please post it as an answer as i still have this same issue.

Comment: Thx - I had read your post before I added this but to be honest - I'm not that great at excel - I did try some of the suggestions but couldn't get them to work for me

Comment: I would just load 3 queries with all the data, including the Region column. Then I would explain to the users how to filter a table in Excel.